# how to connect to onedrive from server, but sending the data to the frontend(ui)?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, backend, onedrive, azure-ad-msal

hey i have been using the msal.net framework in order to log in and save access for the onedrive of users by doing the code below what it does it prints the user the website (https://microsoft.com/devicelogin) and the code that you will need to enter there

```
var result = await _msalClient.AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode(_scopes, callback =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(callback.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }).ExecuteAsync();
```

my problem is that atm i want to switch it from console base code to an api with frontend and backend
now i know that i want my connection to be done via the backend(c#) but i want it to send the code that the user will need to enter if you go to https://microsoft.com/devicelogin back to the frontend. but because of the wait i cant do it with the current flow of my code, does anyone have any suggestion\insight on how to do it?

Comment: @jdweng yea but you can do it if its all on the asp . net stack what can i do if i want the ui to be written in angular\react?
more specificly i dont see how roles has anything to do with onedrive authentication,
again the main question i am asking is how to convert it from console base app to server side of application that does authentication against azure ad\one drive

Comment: Yea but I don't want the user to pass credentials in the front end/server i want it with device authentication

Comment: I must be missing something what does ROLES has to do with onedrive authentication? I don't want to use c#/.net web-forms for the authentication I just want a way to pass the code back to the frontend server

Comment: Angular is a a web form (a client) connecting to a web server.  So the client credentials has to be passed through the server to the One Drive Connection.

Comment: i am not sure you understood the question... reread it or something... 
again the main question is how to convert this part of code to be changed into something that delivers the code back to the frontend

Comment: I understand your posting.  You agreed with my description of a two port server,

Comment: no, the frontend and backend does not exists on the same server

Comment: two port server = two applications on the same server?
I mean you keep refering me to docs from 2008... its so deprecated that its even says older version in the title...
also i have typed two port application in google keeps giving me electric stuffs if you dont have relevant information from the past 3-5 years so just...
i suggest you read about what i was asking from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp-calls-graph

Comment: Everything you just said in the last comment has 0 to do (and i already knew it so no need to learn it) with what i am trying to do but thank you for trying :D
Have you read the documentation about what i am trying to do?

Comment: I keep on saying you have to pass the credential from the Front End User to the Back End connection.  You have a two port application.  Port one is the Front End and Port two is the Back End.  You need to use Roles.  Here is a newer link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.roles?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

well i figure out its not possible to do it.(or at least thats how i understand it - would love to stand corrected)

basicly because when i get the code(to be entered at https://microsoft.com/devicelogin) and because i want it for non authentication reasons but for authorization for onedrive(to be able to access thier files on onedrive).

I cannot pass the token back to the frontend but i can pass it through the user phone\email(or something like that

I think you can only use msal via non interactive or via the webapp not via the server in interactive way.

Hopefully someone too will find this info helpful